# Javascript sql database connection error

Tags: javascript, sql

I am trying to make a button that writes something in a SQL database with a piece of javascript code. But i am constantly getting this error:

0x80040e21 Runtime-error JavaScript with an ole db action that contains multiple steps errors were occurred.

Here is my code:

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication9.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
    var connection = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");

    var connectionstring = "Data Source=LP12;Initial Catalog=SmmsData;Integrated Security=True";

    connection.Open(connectionstring);
    var rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");

    rs.Open("INSERT INTO SysteemSensorInfo (SysteemNr,DrukSensor) VALUES (1,200)", connection);
    rs.MoveFirst
    while (!rs.eof) {
        document.write(rs.fields(1));
        rs.movenext;
    }

    rs.close;
    connection.close;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>

<h1>A Web Page</h1>
<p id="demo">A Paragraph</p>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

</body>
</html>
```

The error seems to occur when it is reading the connecting string. The program breaks at this point: connection.Open(connectionstring). I have used this connection string a few times in C# code in other programs. So the mistake has to be something else.

Could you please help me?

Comment: It seems to me a horrible idea to allow the browser to directly access a database, but if you must, are you sure the user is on the same network and can access the database?

Comment: This is an extremely wrong way of achieving what you want

Comment: If you *really* want to do this in the client, in IE only, with a LAN based database - then consider a C# SqlConnection knows you want to connect to SQL Server however ADODB.Connection does not, you must tell it by specifying a provider name, see https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-native-client-11-0-oledb-provider/ for example

Comment: INSERT returns no rows btw.

Comment: While you have a specific problem that you want to solve, the approach is so wrong that you will hardly find the right answer without re thinking the way you are connecting to the database

Comment: this is a terrible idea, even if you can get it to work. If this is for an intranet, it might work, because the users are likely to be on the same network as the DB, but for a public website it won't (or shouldn't, if your DB security is OK). But by doing this in JS, you expose the location and name of your database to everybody - anyone can view the source code of a web page. They could use the info to run queries you don't want them to. It will also be very slow in comparison to doing it in C#. Lastly you need to review your SQL - an INSERT statement does not return any rows.

Comment: I know this is a wrong way to connect to a database. But i was trying to find out if it was possible. I will rewrite my code in c# and change things up.